# Как записать SQL запрос?

Tags: mysql, sql

**table1** [name] [value] **table2** [name] [parent]

известен один **name**, как в **table1** поменять **value** у тех **name**, у которых в **table2** такой же **parent** как и у известного **name**? Можно  ли вообще это сделать одним запросом update или придется сначала делать select что бы узнать parent, а потом update join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый день! Можно вот так

```
UPDATE [table1]
   SET [value] = 'newvalue'
 WHERE [name] IN (SELECT t1.[name]
                    FROM [table2] t1
                   WHERE t1.[parent] = (SELECT t2.[parent]
                                          FROM [table2]
                                         WHERE t2.[name] = 'customname'))
```

Вариант с JOIN:

```
UPDATE [table1]
   SET [value] = 'newvalue'
 WHERE [name] IN
          (SELECT t2.[name]
             FROM [table2] t1
                  JOIN [table2] t2
                     ON     t1.[parent] = t2.[parent]
                        AND t1.[name] = 'customname')
```

Comment: добавьте пожалуйста вариант с join, мне интересно как это будет выглядеть, спасибо

Comment: @ArtGrek13 Добавил. Пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table1 t1, table2 t21, table2 t22
SET t1.value = 'newvalue'
WHERE t1.name = t21.name
  AND t21.parent = t22.parent
  AND t22.name = 'customname'

UPDATE table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t21 ON t1.name = t21.name
  JOIN table2 t22 ON t21.parent = t22.parent
SET t1.value = 'newvalue'
WHERE t22.name = 'customname'


UPDATE table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t21 ON t1.name = t21.name
  JOIN table2 t22 ON t21.parent = t22.parent
                 AND t22.name = 'customname'
SET t1.value = 'newvalue'
```